# Requests from cache are served with no CORS headers

Tags: azure, cors, azure-api-management

After configuring an operation with caching and CORS, hitting the endpoint returns the desired CORS headers only when the response is from a cache miss.
When the response is fetched from the cache, the headers are missing.

The configuration for the operation is:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false">
            <vary-by-header>Accept</vary-by-header>
            <vary-by-header>Accept-Charset</vary-by-header>
        </cache-lookup>
        <cors allow-credentials="true">
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>http://example.com</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods>
                <!-- allow any -->
                <method>*</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <!-- allow any -->
                <header>*</header>
            </allowed-headers>
        </cors>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <cache-store duration="300" />
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of nodes in the policy matters. Having the `cache-lookup` element before the `cors` element resulted in the response being fetched from the cache, and then immediately return, without falling through to the `cors` directive to add the headers. 
The solution was to reverse the order of the two elements so that `cors` appears before `cache-lookup`, which means it is always invoked and adds the relevant headers to the response, regardless of whether it comes from the cache or not.